# PostGreSQL CREATE TABLE with PDO PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I try to do a simple create table in my PostgreSQL datatable, by executing the createTables function bellow:

```
    public function createTables() {
        try {
            $db = new PDO('pgsql:host='.$this->PARAM_hote.';port='.$this->PARAM_port.';dbname='.$this->PARAM_nom_bd.';user='.$this->PARAM_utilisateur.';password='.$this->PARAM_mot_passe);

            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql ='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, prename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);';
            $db->exec($sql);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

But I still have:

```
testSQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « ( » LINE 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT P... ^
```

And I don't know why ?...

Thanks for help

Comment: God, localized error messages suck :P

Comment: You're using MySQL syntax. Don't expect that to work in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no autoincrement in postgresql. In instead use `serial`. And the `integer` type is always 4 bytes.

```
test (id serial PRIMARY KEY,
```

The `serial` type implies integer with a `not null` constraint and an attached sequence.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: Thanks Clodoaldo Neto, but $sql ='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, prename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);'; work, but without autoincrement, but $sql ='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT serial PRIMARY KEY, prename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);'; return an error to:  SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « serial » LINE 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT serial PRIMARY KEY, ... ^

Comment: [Integer is 4 bytes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html). Bigint is 8 bytes.  In MySQL, `int(11)` gives a hint about the maximum display width (11 characters).

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Absolutely correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Macbernie Ok, fixed.